# Helm Error converting YAML to JSON: yaml: line 20: did not find expected key

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm, go-templates

I don't really know what is the error here, is a simple helm deploy with a _helpers.tpl, it doesn't make sense and is probably a stupid mistake, the code:

deploy.yaml

```yaml
apiVersion: apps/v1 # for versions before 1.9.0 use apps/v1beta2
kind: Deployment
{{ include "metadata.name" . }}-deploy
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: nginx
  replicas: 2 # tells deployment to run 2 pods matching the template
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: nginx
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: nginx
        image: nginx:1.14.2
        ports:
        - containerPort: 80
        vars: {{- include "envs.var" .Values.secret.data }}
```

_helpers.tpl

```yaml
{{- define "envs.var"}}
{{- range $key := . }}
- name: {{ $key | upper | quote}}
  valueFrom:
    secretKeyRef:
      key: {{ $key | lower }}
      name: {{ $key }}-auth
{{- end }}
{{- end }}
```

values.yaml

```yaml
secret:
  data:
    username: root
    password: test
```

the error

```
Error: YAML parse error on mychart/templates/deploy.yaml: error converting YAML to JSON: yaml: line 21: did not find expected key
```

Comment: can you confirm if the solution provided below worked for you?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here this problem happens because of indent. You can resolve by updating

```
env: {{- include "envs.var" .Values.secret.data | nindent 12  }}
```

Comment: i cant believe the mistake was as stupid as using a wrong word, i guess i really was burned out, fixed it recently and then remembered about this question, thanks for the help anyway

Answer (score 4):

Simplest way to resolve this kind of issues is to use tools.

These are mostly indentation issues, and can be resolved very easily using the right tool

```
 npm install -g yaml-lint
```

yaml-lint is one such tool

```
 PS E:\vsc-workspaces\grafana-1> yamllint .\grafana.yaml
× YAML Lint failed for C:/Users/mnadeem6/vsc-workspaces/grafana-1/grafana.yaml
× bad indentation of a mapping entry at line 137, column 11:
          restartPolicy: Always
          ^
PS E:\vsc-workspaces\grafana-1> yamllint .\grafana.yaml
√ YAML Lint successful.
```

Answer (score 0):

Error: failed to parse .\email-service-values.yaml: error converting YAML to JSON: yaml: line 14: could not find expected ':'

I have got above error, while practicing an use case from "Techworld with Nana" Bootcamp. In my case, indentation is the problem. Got this error when I mentioned **3 (or) more hashes(---)** to separate deployment & service related key values. My issue resolved, Once I **removed those hashes** and just kept an empty line between deployment and service related parameters.

```
appName: emailservice
appReplicas: 2
appImage: gcr.io/google-samples/microservices-demo/emailservice
appVersion: v0.2.3
containerPort: 8080
containerEnvVars: 
- name: PORT
  value: "8080"
- name: DISABLE_TRACING
  value: "1"
- name: DISABLE_PROFILER
  value: "1"
---
servicePort: 5000
serviceType: ClusterIP
```